# can I use a second bluetooth device in linux

Tags: bluetooth

I want to use bluetooth keyboard and bluetooth speackers, however in debian 11, with bluez and blueman. I can use only one at a time, both work just fine, but only solo.

what can be this, a configuration, a missing firmware.

Please help, strugling with this years already.

Comment: If they were missing firmware they wouldn't work at all as solo. Plugin both devices and type "bluetoothctl list" and you should see two devices. See "bluetoothctl help"  - there are number of commands to help you debug your problem. Maybe something went wrong while pairing - did you use a GUI?

Comment: yes, yes, and yes, I use blueman and also bluetoothctl, both can detect and pair both devices, if I connect only one device everything works fine, when I try to connect the second, sometimes connect, others times doesnt, nevertheless the second device connected always doesnt work.

Comment: had also try to troubleshoot the bluetooth devices for missing firmware and errors, had installed the missing files for bluetooh, and dont find any more errors, only when the second device is connected it presents some errors, if only one is connected it works seemless.